# Application error after changing from APP_ENV=local to APP_ENV=production in .env Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .env

So I wanted to deploy my app to production, and I changed from:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```

to

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

However, the API that I had created and its `route` immediately couldn't be accessed, aka an error.
How could this happen?
Are there any further changes that need to be made?

Because previously I could access my route fine when `APP_ENV` was still set to `local` from this address `http://myweb.com/project-folder/public/api/test`, like this:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return 'Hello there!';
});
```

But not after I changed it to `production`. :(

I've run `php artisan env` to confirm the code changes, and also run `php artisan config:clear`, but still after the change, my code can't be accessed..

Please help, thank you

Comment: "*couldn't be accessed, aka an error*" - what error? 404? 500?  Something else? What do your Laravel, PHP and web server logs say? Did you make any changes other than to `.env`?  IIRC you cannot cache route closures like the one you've shown, did you try to cache routes, and if so, have you tried clearing the route (and other) caches?

Comment: Environment variables shouldn't affect routing. Can you be more clear as to what happens when you hit the URL? Also, why do I see `public` in your URI?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Its 404 Not Found, i tried it using Postman.. The changes i've made to the .env are just `APP_ENV`, `APP_DEBUG` and sql server connection. And i dont know where to see the server logs? Its still in local development. And also html code 404 error returned in Postman testing..

Comment: @nice_dev Yeah, it shouldn't affect it right? When i hit the URL, i just to get the returned value, or something else i code, but right when i change the `APP_ENV` to `production`, it can't be accessed.. Why there is a `public` in my url is because to help me to access the API, I haven't changed the base URL path yet..

Comment: The very first step when debugging is check your logs.  If you don't know where to find them, check the docs/start searching.  Your Laravel log should be (by default) in `storage/logs/laravel.log`.  You might also want to turn `APP_DEBUG` back on to see more info about the problem  (I am assuming you are not really in production and your app is not public, turning APP_DEBUG on might expose sensitive info in error msgs).  Note you also have `/public` in your URL which means your web server is not configured correctly, and this is a security risk, do not go live like that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I checked `laravel.log` but it doesn't say anything there, how can this happen?
Thanks for the advice about `public` security, i'll update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a problem with your web server settings. Please check the directory path in nginx or apache .
The default path should be the path to your index file

If you are from local or using a shared host, please check the .htacess file .

If the problem is not solved, check this in .env file . they

```
APP_URL=http://myweb.com 
APP_BASE_PATH=/var/www/myweb.com/public_html
```

Comment: Wow you're right, i forgot to change the `APP_URL`! Omg.. Thanks